# How do you set the position of a Combobox grid

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am using a combobox in my GUI code. Even though I specify the row and column value, I couldn't see combobox being positioned. I did an online research in many places and ended up rising the question here. Please help me out with this.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

root = Tk()
w = 455
h = 245

ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

x  = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y  = (hs/2) - (h/2)

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

value = StringVar()
box = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=value, state='readonly')
box['values'] = ('A', 'B', 'C')
box.current(0)
box.grid(column=10, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Rows and columns with no widgets in them have a height/width of 0, so using `(column=10, row=0)` with columns 0-9 empty still puts the widget all the way to the left. If all you want is place the widget a bit from the side, use padding ([`padx` and `pady`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method)).

Comment: @fhdrsdg Thank You :)